# How to manually set a data on a datagridview column between 2 dates?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, visual-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHogi.jpg)

i have this datagridview that has 2 date columns named : "SOA RECIEVED" and  "DATE PAID". What i wanted to do is to compute the difference and show the result on the column name "NO. OF DAYS PAID"

Comment: What have  you tried so far? What exactly are you having trouble with? Getting the info to perform the calculation? Performing the calculation? Creating an additional column? Populating that additional column?

Comment: You can attach your code appropriately, it will be more helpful for others to help you

Answer (score 0):

To manually set data on the "NO. OF DAYS PAID" column based on the "SOA RECEIVED" and "DATE PAID" columns, you can use the `CellFormatting` event of the `DataGridView` control. This event allows you to customize the display of data in the grid. Here's a step-by-step guide on how to achieve this in C#:

1. Subscribe to the `CellFormatting` event of your `DataGridView`. You can do this either in the designer or in code:

```cs
dataGridView1.CellFormatting += DataGridView1_CellFormatting;
```

2. Implement the `CellFormatting` event handler:

```cs
private void DataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    // Check if we are formatting the "NO. OF DAYS PAID" column
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "NO. OF DAYS PAID")
    {
        // Check if the current row is not a header row and has data in "SOA RECEIVED" and "DATE PAID" columns
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0 &&
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["SOA RECEIVED"].Value != null &&
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["DATE PAID"].Value != null)
        {
            DateTime soaReceived = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["SOA RECEIVED"].Value);
            DateTime datePaid = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["DATE PAID"].Value);

            // Calculate the difference in days and set the value for "NO. OF DAYS PAID" column
            int noOfDaysPaid = (datePaid - soaReceived).Days;
            e.Value = noOfDaysPaid.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

3. Make sure the column names match the ones in your DataGridView.

With this code, whenever the DataGridView needs to display data in the "NO. OF DAYS PAID" column, it will calculate the difference between the dates in the "SOA RECEIVED" and "DATE PAID" columns and show the result in the "NO. OF DAYS PAID" column.

Comment: Hello iumar28, why does it say invalid column name "SOA RECEIVED"?